# Unable to resolve google-service dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase

I am setting up the first project of android with firebase following this [Add Firebase to Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk) docs and stuck at resolving google play service dependency it says

[image]

I also google it but couldn't find any helpful answer.

**In Project:Gradle**

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

**In App:Gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is anything i am missing? what should i do as i read my answers here at stackoverflow but none of them were useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set up the plugin and dependencies correctly, but you need the `google-services.json` configuration file from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

If you've not connected an app, select "Add Firebase to your Android app", enter the package name, and hit *Add App*. This should download the file.

If you connected before, click on the cog in the left nav, select *Project Settings*, and download the `google-services.json` associated with your project.

You need to download this and put in your `app` directory (next to the app `build.gradle`).

Answer (score 0):

for me solved by add this In Project:Gradle
in :

```
buildscript {
     ///////////////////*blah blah*/
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
     repositories {
        jcenter()
     }
}
```